# is there a Python library to implement VBA code?

Tags: python, vba, ms-word

My goal is to extract all charts and shapes in a word document into images in a folder. I couldn't find anyway to do it using python, I tried multiple libraries and methods but none of them work. However, I found a way using VBA Macros. I want to implement the codes I wrote using python, Is there any library that would allow me to do that?

My First functions basically turns shapes into pictures by cutting and pasting it as a picture

```
Sub SaveShapes()
    For Each s In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        s.Select
        Selection.Cut
        Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=27, Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    Next s
End Sub
```

Second Function loops through all inlineShapes and if the object is a chart it saves it as a picture

```
Sub SaveCharts()
    Dim docCurrent As Document
    Dim shapeCurrent As InlineShape
    Dim RC As Integer
    Dim vData() As Byte
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lWritePos As Long
    Dim strOutFileName As String

    Set docCurrent = ActiveDocument

    i = 1

    For Each shapeCurrent In docCurrent.InlineShapes
        If shapeCurrent.HasChart Then
        
            strOutFileName = "c:\temp\chart" & CStr(i) & ".emf"
            Open strOutFileName For Binary Access Write As #1
            i = i + 1
            vData = shapeCurrent.Range.EnhMetaFileBits
            lWritePos = 1
    
            Put #1, lWritePos, vData
    
            Close #1
        End If
 Next shapeCurrent
End Sub
```

I mainly want to implement these 2 functions in python, but other ideas I came up with was saving them as VBS scripts and running using cmd but that didn't work because it would be too slow and MS word would not open the document because it was not trusted.
The other idea I have is just running them as macros natively on VBA in word, but that would be the second best approach in my opinion.

Comment: Why is running macros natively in Word a second-best approach?

Comment: its the second-best thing i can think of

Comment: IMO it's the best approach. What's the benefit of rewriting in Python? You're likely going to have to use `win32com` for that. I see no upside and a lot of work to replace an already feasible solution.

Comment: I checked win32com and their documentation is horrible, the main reason I want it to be only in python is because other people may use the tool im making and I want to spare them the set up

Comment: What "setup" are you referring to? Put the code in a .dotm file, place the .dotm in Word's startup folder. Job done.

Comment: @JohnKorchok can you explain more? in word's startup folder as in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16" ?

Comment: Startup folder location can be found under File | Options | Advanced | General | File Locations | Startup

Comment: The default Word Startup location in Windows is C:\Users\[YourActualUserName]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\Startup. A simple way to open this folder is to paste in this line in a File Explorer window: _%appdata%\Microsoft\Word\Startup_

Answer (score 0):

You can run a VBA macro with `pywin32`.

```py
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'D:\temp\PyRunVBA.xlsm')
try:
    excel.Application.Run("Module1.InsertDate")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", e)
workbook.Save()
workbook.Close()
excel.Quit()
```